# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration'

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I have created a Spring/Maven project in Eclipse. Then I put it on a server under svn. Then I import it in Eclipse again using import > maven project, etc.

My current `App.java` application contains the following code:

```
package com.mycomany.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

But when I try to run this file I receive this error:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.3.RELEASE)

2016-03-08 16:50:14.234  INFO 11348 --- [           main] com.mycomany.app.App                     : Starting App on nelsons-mbp.mobile.usilu.net with PID 11348 (/Users/cell/Desktop/Salamander/my-app/target/classes started by cell in /Users/cell/Desktop/Salamander/my-app)
2016-03-08 16:50:14.236  INFO 11348 --- [           main] com.mycomany.app.App                     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-03-08 16:50:14.278  INFO 11348 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6cc7b4de: startup date [Tue Mar 08 16:50:14 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-03-08 16:50:14.866  INFO 11348 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-03-08 16:50:14.925  INFO 11348 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2b887bf6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-03-08 16:50:15.272  INFO 11348 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-03-08 16:50:15.283  INFO 11348 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-03-08 16:50:15.284  INFO 11348 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
2016-03-08 16:50:15.360  INFO 11348 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-03-08 16:50:15.360  INFO 11348 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1086 ms
2016-03-08 16:50:15.400  INFO 11348 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-03-08 16:50:15.456  WARN 11348 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2016-03-08 16:50:15.465  INFO 11348 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-03-08 16:50:15.471  WARN 11348 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
2016-03-08 16:50:15.478 ERROR 11348 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.mycomany.app.App.main(App.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:180) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:121) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted

2016-03-08 16:50:15.482  INFO 11348 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Users/cell/Desktop/Salamander/my-app/target/classes/, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.5/logback-core-1.1.5.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.16/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.16/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.8/aspectjweaver-1.8.8.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.4.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.16/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.32/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-juli-8.0.32.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jersey/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jersey-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.32.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.5/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.5/jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.5/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-server/2.22.2/jersey-server-2.22.2.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-common/2.22.2/jersey-common-2.22.2.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/repackaged/jersey-guava/2.22.2/jersey-guava-2.22.2.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/osgi-resource-locator/1.0.1/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-client/2.22.2/jersey-client-2.22.2.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/media/jersey-media-jaxb/2.22.2/jersey-media-jaxb-2.22.2.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-api/2.4.0-b34/hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-utils/2.4.0-b34/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/aopalliance-repackaged/2.4.0-b34/aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/javax.inject/2.4.0-b34/javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-locator/2.4.0-b34/hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/containers/jersey-container-servlet-core/2.22.2/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.2.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/containers/jersey-container-servlet/2.22.2/jersey-container-servlet-2.22.2.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/ext/jersey-bean-validation/2.22.2/jersey-bean-validation-2.22.2.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/ext/jersey-spring3/2.22.2/jersey-spring3-2.22.2.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.4.0-b34/hk2-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/config-types/2.4.0-b34/config-types-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-core/2.4.0-b34/hk2-core-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-config/2.4.0-b34/hk2-config-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/tiger-types/1.4/tiger-types-1.4.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-runlevel/2.4.0-b34/hk2-runlevel-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/class-model/2.4.0-b34/class-model-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/external/asm-all-repackaged/2.4.0-b34/asm-all-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/spring-bridge/2.4.0-b34/spring-bridge-2.4.0-b34.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/media/jersey-media-json-jackson/2.22.2/jersey-media-json-jackson-2.22.2.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jersey/ext/jersey-entity-filtering/2.22.2/jersey-entity-filtering-2.22.2.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base/2.6.5/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.6.5.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.6.5/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.6.5.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.6.5/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.6.5.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar, file:/Users/cell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar]
```

I've no idea why I'm having this problem, but I guess I shouldn't have it. I'm really new to these things.

Comment: EnableAutoConfiguration is not required - you already use springBootApplication annotation. stacktrace shows you have not mentioned the embedded database details

Comment: in your pom include some embedded db dependency like hsql or h2.. it should work fine then

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan How can I specify them? Do you know a tutorial?

Answer (score 11):

Since your class is annotated with `SpringBootApplication`, `EnableAutoConfiguration` is not required.
Going by the stacktrace, Spring container is not able to figure out the type of embedded database. In your pom.xml file, include the below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

or the following for mySQL

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: or any other embedded db of your choice

Comment: We're using MySQL...how can I specify for it?

Comment: Actually, I've already this on my pom.xml: `  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  `

Comment: Also, I've nothing specified in `src/main/resources/application.properties` (it's empty), could this be the problem?

Comment: I'm also having this warning: `Description Resource Path Location Type
Classpath entry org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.   my-app  P/my-app Classpath Dependency Validator Message
`... I've tried for hours, but nothing yet..

Comment: derby,hsqldb,h2 are the embedded types spring supports with just pom entries... MySQL configuration is well explained in their official docs. refer http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: I've add to `application.properties`  this code `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/Salamander
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, but now I've another error: `Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory`...(where root is in my case my password and username)...

Comment: plz post those details (application.props,pom.xml etc) in your question as edits and not as comments. This will make it easier for other also to help. Include the stacktrace and pom.xml, consider tagging this question as spring-boot

Answer (score 7):

this springboot start class add annotation -

`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after adding dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

into **pom.xml**.

The solution was to define a database setting in application.properties. In my case i added the next:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/webdemodb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem could ne in that: your test class not in a specific package. When i put my test class to the root i see alike message

Answer (score 0):

Ensure u specify the right driver in the .properties file.

E.g for postgres: `spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver`

Answer (score -1):

Remove the @Bean annotation in **DataSource** return type method.

Comment: Where do you remove the annotation?