# Failed to determine a suitable driver class in CMD

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Im developing spring boot Rest API, application,
In my VS code application is running without any runtime errors and working with postman too,
VS code runtime output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baC2P.png)
however, when i export the JAR file via VS code, and try to run cmd, that file pop up run time error,
ERROR

> Blockquote
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PP4lp.png)
>
> Blockquote
> Error Msg in cmd

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

My POM XML

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

application.properties

```
## Server Properties
server.port= 8083
server.servlet.context-path= /TEST-API

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TEST?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&zerodatetimebehavior=Converttonull
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= 1234
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Please include the error message as text in your question

Comment: @sorifiend I have updated just now.

Comment: Looks like you may not have included the mysql dependency, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872327/error-creating-bean-with-name-org-springframework-boot-autoconfigure-orm-jpa-hi also if that was not the casu, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214538/org-springframework-beans-factory-unsatisfieddependencyexception-error-creating and

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have check those articles. but no help with that

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

Try use

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

instead of

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

in your properties file, **if you are using mysql version < 8**

### Option 2

Check if your driver of mysql (JAR file) was included in the library of WAR --> WEB-INF/lib.

### Option 3

If you are not fix it yet, and you have other database in your machine like a postgres:

- change this connection to this another database.
- test inside of your editor/ide
- export to war
- if the problem happens the same way, you can be right that your export process is the problem. So try use the plugin of maven to generate the war: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Yes I did this update too.. but its running in vs code with both options. but when it's start to run jar file same error pop in up

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support
one of my friends help me to fix the issue
what they did is,
delete mvnw file from the project path.
Then paste apache-maven-3.6.0 in to **C** driver and then
did the maven install and package the project in vs code.
After that project jar generated.